# Why is Station Object Null inside the For-Each Loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am writing a basic program that iterates through an array of objects. I am then making a for-each loop and setting the values of each object in the array from user input. However, I am getting a null-pointer exception on the object I am using to store the value of the object array.

Here is my code:
import javax.swing.*;

```
public class Calculation {


public static Stations[] createStationArray(){
int numOfStations;
String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many stations are there?");
numOfStations = Integer.parseInt(string);
Stations[] stations = new Stations[numOfStations];
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, stations.length);
return stations;

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Stations[] stations;
    stations = createStationArray();
        System.out.println("stations array value" + stations);

    for(Stations station : stations)
{System.out.println("station variable value" + station);
        int stationNum = 1;
        double amountOfWaste;
        station.setStationNum(stationNum);
        String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is this Station's waste amount?");
        amountOfWaste = Double.parseDouble(string);
        station.setWaste(amountOfWaste);
        System.out.println("Station " + station.getStationNum() + " has a waste amount of " + station.getWaste());
    }

}
}
```

I am having issues in the for-each loop with the variable "station".
It is supposed to be the current object in the array list. However, I am getting a null-pointer exception. Here is the console output.

```
stations array value[LStations;@28787c16
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Calculation.main(Calculation.java:27)
station variable value null
erException
at Calculation.main(Calculation.java:27)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created an array of stations, but did not populate it. So when you loop over the array, every entry is still null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the Stations before calling methods on it. Try adding this inside createStationArray() after instantiating the Stations array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfStations; i++) 
    stations[i] = new Stations();
```